# what is this representation of integer java.lang.Integer##0V@AQKgaAo

Tags: java, android, preferences, shared

It's quiet new to me. I found it inside an shared preferences xml file in Android app.
`java.lang.Integer##0V@AQKgaAo3PXH4NHbF2iQY0eCAxrKVEmjJq23QWVrJxlbc`

How do i decode this to normal integer. Also there are several other string for `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Boolean` how can I decode those also?

**P.S.** I found how it is created. It seems app uses a library called [hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk). According to their page it's **Secure, simple key-value storage for android.** As far as I understood it converts the  value to it's string representation then encrypts it with facebook conceal library , convert it with some converter and then store it in storage

Comment: that does not look like an integer. How did you write it to shared preferences?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know because it's a third party app.

Comment: then it is done for a reason for you not to be able to get the real value. You should not get that value.

Comment: Just curious since I've never seen this type of value. So I could use it for my apps if it's useful

Comment: Just *encrypted* value. Nobody knows how exactly. If you want to do something similar - encrypt the values you put into shared preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an instance of an object of the class `Integer`, not to be confused with the primitive type `int`. It's not encoded. That references to the object instance, which is very likely a protected constant, like an encryption key or so.

**Edit:** I'm not familiar with Android, only raw Java, but what you want is to create a constant object available to be referenced throughout any interested sections of your app. That way, the value of interest will exist only once in your code. I only know this is an object reference because I recognize that representation you've pointed and, yes, it is created by Java itself.

Comment: Can you help with some example of how to create that protected constant? Could it be some custom string format to fool intruder or something that's generated by Java itself?

Comment: I found how it is created. It seems app uses a library called [hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk). According to their page it's **Secure, simple key-value storage for android**. As far as I understood it converts the the <T> value to it's string representation then encrypts it with facebook conceal , convert it with some converter and then store it in storage.